# error in Advanced Search Form for Custom Post Types in WordPress array_key_exists() expects parameter 2to be array, string given

Tags: custom-post-types, search

I am building an [advanced search form](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-advanced-search-form-in-wordpress-for-custom-post-types/) but the search is showing all post all time with this error too `array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, string was given`

this is my code in `header.php`

```
<?php $query_types = get_query_var('post_type'); ?>
<?php

     $args = array(
                 'public'   => true,
                 '_builtin' => false
             );

     $output = 'names'; // names or objects, note names is the default
     $operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'

     $post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator ); 

     //array array_slice ( array $array , int $offset [, int $length = NULL [, bool $preserve_keys = false ]] ) see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php
    foreach ( array_slice($post_types, 0, 5) as $post_type ) { //display max 5 post_type
         ?> 
    <li>
        <a>
           <input id="<?php  echo $post_type ?>" class="btn btn-lg" type="checkbox" name="post_type[]" value="<?php  echo $post_type ?>" <?php if (!empty($query_types) && array_key_exists($post_type , $query_types)) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>/> 
           <!-- array_key_exists($post_type , $query_types) -->
           <label for="<?php  echo $post_type ?>"><span><?php  echo $post_type ?></span></label> 
       </a> 
    </li> 
 <?php 
} 
?>
```

in `searchform.php` a have this:

```
<?php
    $postType = array("construction","renovation","agrandissement","bradage");

    foreach ($postType as &$value) {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="'.$value.'" />';
    }
    unset($value); // break the reference with the last element
?>
```

when I add `&& is_array($query_types)` in header.php  `array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given` doesn`t show anymore but the result is empty.
i also get

```
%5B%5D
```

in the url

```
mywebsite.com/?s=LED70266765IKEA&post_type%5B%5D=boutique
```

please help me figuring out what I am doing wrong.

**UPDATE:**

here is my `search.php`

```
<?php

 if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

?>
```

```
<section id="primary" class="row">
    <main id="main" class="container" role="main">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <header class="page-header">
            <h5 class="page-title">
                <?php printf( __( 'Résultats de recherche pour: %s', 'igorconstructions' ), '<span>' . esc_html( get_search_query() ) . '</span>' ); ?>
            </h5>
        </header><!-- .page-header --> 
        <?php
        // Start the loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            /**
             * Run the loop for the search to output the results.
             * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
             * called content-search.php and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'search' );

        // End the loop.
        endwhile;
        ?>
        <!-- PAGINATION -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="paging-navigation text-right">
                    <?php    
                        the_posts_pagination( array(
                            'screen_reader_text' => ( '' ),
                            'type'      => 'list',
                            'end_size'      => 3,
                            'mid_size'      => 3,
                            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                            'prev_text' => '<span class="icon-angle-left">&larr;</span>',
                            'next_text' => '<span class="icon-angle-right">&rarr;</span>',
                            'before_page_number' => 'Page',
                            'after_page_number'  => '', 
                        ) ); 
                    ?>      
                </div><!--  end pagination container -->
            </div><!-- end large-12 -->
        </div>
        <!-- end PAGINATION -->
        <?php 
    // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
    else :
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

    endif;
    ?>

    </main><!-- .site-main -->
</section><!-- .content-area -->
```

and `content-search.php` looks like this:

```
 <?php if(isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
    $type = $_GET['post_type'];
    //$type = $wp_query->query['post_type'];
    if ( in_array( $type, array('boutique','news','text') ) ) {?>

    <section class="col-md-4">
        <article id="product-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>    
            <!--
                Thumbnail
            -->
            <div class="product-image">
                <figure  class="product-thumb">
                    <!-- === Confitional thumbnail=== -->
                    <?php if (  (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail())) : ?> 
                            <!--Image size //thumbnail medium large full-->
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium', 'blog-thumb', array('class' => 'blog-thumb')); ?>

                            <?php else :?>

                            <img class="blog-thumb" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/cat-images/<?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->slug; ?>.jpg" /> 

                    <?php endif; ?>
                </figure>
            </div>

            <div class="product-description">
                 <!--
                    The Title
                -->
                <h4>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="m'en dire plus à ce sujet '<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>' svp!"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </h4>
                <P>
                    <?php 
                        $url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'price', true ); 

                        if ($url) {
                            echo '<strong>à partir de:</strong> <strong class=thumbnail-price>'.$url.' FCFA TTC</strong>/ Unité';
                        }
                    ?>
                </P> 
            </div>

            <div class="user-actions">
            <!--
                User actions
            -->

                <!-- Product reference-->

                <p class="text-right">
                    <strong>Référence: </strong>
                    <span><?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'reference', true ) ?></span>
                </p>
                <p class="text-right">
                    <button class="action-btn-prim">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Voir l'article</a>
                    </button>
                </p>
                <form class="text-right"> 
                    <button class="add-to-cart action-bt"> 
                        <a><svg class="pull-left" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns" width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 29 30" version="1.1">

                            <g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Group">
                                <path fill="floralwhite" d="M5.87076823,28.1796875 C4.57567676,28.1796875 3.52246094,27.1264717 3.52246094,25.8313802 C3.52246094,24.5362887 4.57567676,23.4830729 5.87076823,23.4830729 C7.1658597,23.4830729 8.21907552,24.5362887 8.21907552,25.8313802 C8.21907552,27.1264717 7.1658597,28.1796875 5.87076823,28.1796875 L5.87076823,28.1796875 Z M5.87076823,24.6572266 C5.22322249,24.6572266 4.69661458,25.1838345 4.69661458,25.8313802 C4.69661458,26.4789259 5.22322249,27.0055339 5.87076823,27.0055339 C6.51831396,27.0055339 7.04492188,26.4789259 7.04492188,25.8313802 C7.04492188,25.1838345 6.51831396,24.6572266 5.87076823,24.6572266 L5.87076823,24.6572266 Z" id="Shape"/>
                                <path fill="floralwhite" d="M18.7864583,28.1796875 C17.4913669,28.1796875 16.438151,27.1264717 16.438151,25.8313802 C16.438151,24.5362887 17.4913669,23.4830729 18.7864583,23.4830729 C20.0815498,23.4830729 21.1347656,24.5362887 21.1347656,25.8313802 C21.1347656,27.1264717 20.0815498,28.1796875 18.7864583,28.1796875 L18.7864583,28.1796875 Z M18.7864583,24.6572266 C18.1389126,24.6572266 17.6123047,25.1838345 17.6123047,25.8313802 C17.6123047,26.4789259 18.1389126,27.0055339 18.7864583,27.0055339 C19.4340041,27.0055339 19.960612,26.4789259 19.960612,25.8313802 C19.960612,25.1838345 19.4340041,24.6572266 18.7864583,24.6572266 L18.7864583,24.6572266 Z" id="Shape"/>
                                <path fill="floralwhite" d="M12.3286133,9.39322917 C12.0039598,9.39322917 11.7415365,9.13080583 11.7415365,8.80615234 L11.7415365,0.587076823 C11.7415365,0.26242334 12.0039598,0 12.3286133,0 C12.6532668,0 12.9156901,0.26242334 12.9156901,0.587076823 L12.9156901,8.80615234 C12.9156901,9.13080583 12.6532668,9.39322917 12.3286133,9.39322917 L12.3286133,9.39322917 Z" id="Shape"/>
                                <path fill="floralwhite" d="M12.3286133,9.39322917 C12.1783216,9.39322917 12.0280299,9.33569564 11.91355,9.22121566 L8.39108903,5.69875472 C8.16154199,5.46920768 8.16154199,5.09817513 8.39108903,4.86862809 C8.62063607,4.63908105 8.99166862,4.63908105 9.22121566,4.86862809 L12.3286133,7.97602572 L15.4360109,4.86862809 C15.6655579,4.63908105 16.0365905,4.63908105 16.2661375,4.86862809 C16.4956846,5.09817513 16.4956846,5.46920768 16.2661375,5.69875472 L12.7436766,9.22121566 C12.6291966,9.33569564 12.4789049,9.39322917 12.3286133,9.39322917 L12.3286133,9.39322917 Z" id="Shape"/>
                                <path fill="floralwhite" d="M18.7864583,24.6572266 L5.87076823,24.6572266 C5.54611475,24.6572266 5.28369141,24.3948032 5.28369141,24.0701497 C5.28369141,23.7454963 5.54611475,23.4830729 5.87076823,23.4830729 L18.3214935,23.4830729 L22.9112601,3.97509717 C22.9740773,3.70973844 23.2106693,3.52246094 23.4830729,3.52246094 L27.5926107,3.52246094 C27.9172642,3.52246094 28.1796875,3.78488428 28.1796875,4.10953776 C28.1796875,4.43419124 27.9172642,4.69661458 27.5926107,4.69661458 L23.9480378,4.69661458 L19.3582712,24.2045903 C19.2954539,24.4699491 19.058862,24.6572266 18.7864583,24.6572266 L18.7864583,24.6572266 Z" id="Shape"/>
                                <path fill="floralwhite" d="M19.3735352,22.3089193 L4.10953776,22.3089193 C3.85650765,22.3089193 3.63283138,22.1474731 3.55298893,21.9073587 L0.0305279948,11.3399759 C-0.029940918,11.1609175 0.000587076823,10.9636597 0.11095752,10.8110197 C0.221327962,10.6577926 0.398625163,10.5673828 0.587076823,10.5673828 L21.7218424,10.5673828 C22.0464959,10.5673828 22.3089193,10.8298062 22.3089193,11.1544596 C22.3089193,11.4791131 22.0464959,11.7415365 21.7218424,11.7415365 L1.40193945,11.7415365 L4.53282015,21.1347656 L19.3735352,21.1347656 C19.6981886,21.1347656 19.960612,21.397189 19.960612,21.7218424 C19.960612,22.0464959 19.6981886,22.3089193 19.3735352,22.3089193 L19.3735352,22.3089193 Z" id="Shape"/>
                            </g>
                            </svg>
                             Ajouter
                        </a>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </article>
    </section>     
    <?php } 
  elseif($type == 'construction'){


  }
  elseif($type == 'blog'){


   }
 }else { ?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>


<?php if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) : ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <?php get_the_title() ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core issue is that you're having trouble creating a filtered search. Why not use a `pre_get_posts` hook to modify the query before it actually gets called, then you don't need to modify the template files at all:

```
/**
 * Modify WP_Query before it asks the database what data to retrieve
 * Belongs in functions.php
 *
 * @param WP_Query Object $query
 *
 * @return void
 */
function wpse_265499( $query ) {

    // Don't run on admin
    if( $query->is_admin ) {
        return;
    }

    // IF main query and search page
    if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search() ) {

        // IF we have our post type array set 
        if( isset( $_GET, $_GET['post_type'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['post_type'] ) ) {
            $query->set( 'post_type', $_GET['post_type'] );     // Will be set as boutique
        }

    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_265499' );
```

The above would be added to your `functions.php` file and what [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) does is before it goes to the database and grabs the data to be displayed, we can modify what is being requested. In this case we're saying IF we have `post_types` set in the URL as a `$_GET`, grab only those post types. So your main query will now only show the post types assigned in `$_GET` at which point there's no need for the conditional statements in your template.

---

Let's break this down starting with the error itself.

> array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, string was given

So based on the error we know that [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) needs parameter 2 to be an array, so that it can search for a key, but at some point a string was given instead of an array.

As far as I can tell you only have one instance of [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) and it looks like this:

```
array_key_exists( $post_type , $query_types )
```

Combined with the PHP error we can surmise that `$query_types` must be a string instead of the array that we need for [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) to work. Let's look at how `$query_types` is set:

```
$query_types = get_query_var( 'post_type' );
```

If we look at the [`get_query_var()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/) function we see it *can* return an array because the return type is mixed. That being said, we're only asking for **one** `post_type` so it's probably returning a string for the queried post type.

I'm not sure what it is you're trying to accomplish but hopefully that clears up the reason you're getting that error.

Comment: thank you for your time i am just trying to create an advanced search form for CPT somehow i only get all posts as results and that array_key_exists error.

Comment: @Bansoaistheanswer I've updated my answer, you may want to use `pre_get_posts` instead of conditional statements in the template.

Comment: ok now it shows all cpt posts no matter what i search.

Comment: @Bansoaistheanswer I've just tested this in my theme and it works as expected. Given the following query string: `?s=a&post_type%5B%5D=post&post_type%5B%5D=boutique` will only show those two post types. You're removing your conditional code in `content-search.php` ( reverting it back to the original file ) and pasting the `pre_get_posts` hook above into your `functions.php`, right?

Comment: thank you for your help i found the problem it was a line of code i added in `functions.php`  `if ( $query->is_search ) {
        $meta_query_args = array(
          array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value' => $query->query_vars['s'] = '',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
          ) 
        );
        $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query_args);
      };`

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Howdy_McGee is correct, but just to expand upon their answer:

[`get_query_var()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/) is a function that requires one parameter and the second is an optional default value. It is a wrapper for [`WP_Query::get()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L1633) that has the same parameters. This method checks whether `WP_Query->query_vars[ $query_var ]` exists, and if it does, returns that value.

Query vars can be set using the `WP_Query::set()` method, and the value can be anything: null, integer, string, array, object, whatever. So the get method will return anything as long as it exists. In the case it doesn't exist, it will return whatever the second parameter was passed to `get_query_var()`. In this case, that was nothing, so it uses the default of an empty string.

[`array_key_exists()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php), as you've found out, requires that the second parameter be an array. Since we don't know that `get_query_var()` might not return an array, then we need to make sure before we pass it to a function that requires an array as an input.

```
//* Cast as an array
$query_types = (array) get_query_var( 'post_type', [] );
```

[PHP casting to array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting) will "for any of the types integer, float, string, boolean and resource, converting a value to an array results in an array with a single element with index zero and the value of the scalar which was converted."

Since the `$query_types` will be guaranteed to be an array, you shouldn't have that error, and hopefully your advanced search will work as intended.